# iOS local notification will be repeated, but is set in the past. Does it fire?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uilocalnotification

does anyone here know how iOS handles local notifications which are scheduled to a date in the past, but set with a repeat interval?
Will they be handled in the future or will they simply be ignored?

I ask because I have two types of notification dates stored in a SQLite database in my app. One is being repeated and the other one will not be repeated. If I change or delete one of them in the database (through a table view), I will have to reset all notifications and create new ones out of the database (correct me if I'm wrong here!). The problem is that the dates of the repeated ones could already be passed, but I still need them to fire up.

I could not find anything related to my problem in Google or on here.

Comment: It should be simple enough to prove, no? Just give it a minutely refresh interval, set it to the reference date (Jan 1, 2000), and see what happens!

Comment: Just try it. And if your fears are confirmed, meaning that a date in the past would render the entire (repeating) notification invalid, well, then simply set that date towards the current date and your done. In any case, asking this question has taken you more time than a simple experiment would have taken....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I simply tested it today on a real iOS 6.0.1 device. Even if the fire date is set in the past, a notification with a repeat interval will pop up in the correct intervals.
I think in future versions it also will work.